# Pinescript V5 - barcolor() in two different indicators

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have two indicators, that colour bars in different ways. They are used as signals so not many bars will show as coloured.

I am using the standard syntax:

```
barcolor(condition ? color.green : na)
```

This works fine for 1 script, however, it disables all colours from in any others, even when no colors are applied.

For example, if we set up a chart and create 2 indicators which alternate yellow/orange based on an odd/even bar index, only yellow bars will be effected.

```
// Indicator 1
barcolor(barIsEven ? color.yellow : na)

// Indicator 2
barcolor(barIsOdd ? color.orange  na)
```

In this scenario, I would expect the `na` value to disregard the barcolor altogether.

Likewise, if we set indicator1 to `barcolor(na)`, we now see no color at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the visual order. Which ever indicator is brought to the front you will see.
[image: visual order]

Comment: Yeah visual order can prioritize… but I want to show both. That’s my problem 

Answer (score 0):

You should write to same script this two indicators after that you can write this condition in one line.

barcolor(barIsEven ? color.yellow : barIsOdd ? color.orange : na)

Comment: My example above is across 2 indicators. In reality, the logic to determine bar color is not this simple though.